# Can't add Storage Admin role to GCP service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, authorization, google-iam, role-base-authorization

I am looking at the IAM Service Accounts tab in the GCP control panel. I am editing a Service Account. I click "Grant Access," enter the email of the service account I am creating and attempt to add Storage Admin.

[image: IAM Service Accounts tab]

However, there is no such option in the list.

[image: Cannot find 'Storage Admin' in list]

Also, a seemingly equivalent attempt to do this via the CLI fails:

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project-id \
  --member='serviceAccount:github-actions@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com' \
  --role='projects/my-project-id/roles/storage.admin'

ERROR: Policy modification failed. For a binding with condition, run "gcloud alpha iam policies lint-condition" to identify issues in condition.
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role (projects/my-project-id/roles/storage.admin) does not exist in the resource's hierarchy.
```

Clearly, I am failing to understand something about how a service account is supposed to get granted a role.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you already created the service account you can go to IAM Page to add the Storage Admin Role.

1. Go to IAM Page
2. Click Add
3. Enter New Principals (Enter Service Account you created)
4. Select Desired Role. (In your Case Storage Admin).
5. Save

In case you still want to add role using Creating Service Account Pane, Don't  search with Storage instead scroll down to **All Roles** > Hover **Cloud Storage** > Select **Storage Admin**.

You can also do  what John Hanley mentioned using the Cloud Shell.

Comment: This is a great tip, thank you! It's tough to call which is the correct answer between this and John Hanley's, however, you responded directly to my screenshots and nailed it. **We can only see the full list of roles from the main IAM Add menu, but not in the Service Accounts menu.**

Comment: @CharneyKaye if both answers helped you, please consider upvoting them.

Comment: Thank you, I always went to a specific service account and could never find the role to add. But on the IAM page all roles are there. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are doing. Two important concepts. A service account can be both an identity and a resource. You are managing the service account as a resource in the screenshot. Your CLI command is managing the resource as an identity-granted role within a project.

Your CLI command specifies a **custom** role in the project. Did you create a custom role or are you trying to use an existing Google Cloud IAM role?

Most likely you want to do this:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project-id \
  --member='serviceAccount:github-actions@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com' \
  --role='roles/storage.admin'
```

Notice the difference in how the **Role Name** is specified.

Comment: Thanks for this correct insight into my malformed CLI command.  I had to mark the other answer as the solution because it directly addresses the original weirdness I was seeing as a newcomer in my web console.